# display data on next page using ajax on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a cshtml page, `ListZoneRecords.cshtml`. In this page when user presses on particular zone row, its details should be shown in another page. Can I do this in ajax?

```
//ListZoneRecords.cshtml
<script>
$('#btn_sbmt_details').click(function () {
            var id = $('#i_zone_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ZoneModels/GetByKey",
                data: { id: id},
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
            })
        });
 </script>
```

When this button `btn_sbmt_details` is pressed by user, it calls `GetByKey` method in controller. This method searches for id and retrieve details. Now I have to show the details *in another cshtml page* say `ZoneDetails.cshtml`. Is this possible to do using ajax?

My controller method::

```
public JsonResult  GetByKey(int? id)  
    {   var data = (from z in db.ZoneModels 
                where z.ZoneId == id
                select z).ToList();
        return Json(data,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Or, I have to follow the MVC approach of creating view page of `GetByKey` method and then do `return View(data);`

```
public ActionResult GetByKey(int? id)  
    {   var data = (from z in db.ZoneModels 
                where z.ZoneId == id
                select z).ToList();
        return View(data);
    }
```

Comment: You can return view and display on same screen, but better approach is to create an action for `ZoneDetails.cshtml` and pass `id` via url to that action and simply navigate to that url, e.g. `/ZoneModels/ZoneDetails?id=1`

Comment: @as-if-i-code please can you write the details... I understood the concept but do not know how to do this. Thank You!!!

Comment: please refer answer below

Answer (score 0):

Create an action for `ZoneDetails.cshtml` within your controller(I assume it is `ZoneModelsController.cs`)
Now simply navigate to that action and pass `id` via query string, you would get an url similar to following `/ZoneModels/ZoneDetails?id=1`

Below is a template for the same.

**ListZoneRecords.cshtml**

```
<script>
$('#btn_sbmt_details').click(function () {
    var id = $('#i_zone_id').val();
    window.location = "/ZoneModels/ZoneDetails?id=" + id;
});
 </script>
```

**ZoneModelsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ZoneDetails(int? id)  
{
    List<Object> detailsListy = GetByKey(id);
    
    // write code here to prepare view model
    
    return View(model); 
}

public List<Object>  GetByKey(int? id)  
{   
    var data = (from z in db.ZoneModels 
                where z.ZoneId == id
                select z).ToList();
    return data;
}
```